# Are there any references of Solar Cycles in our scriptures?

Tags: scripture, universe

Just wanted to know more about 'Solar Cycles' from scriptures point of view, their effects on human race or entire earth for that matter.

So my question is are there any references of Solar Cycles in our scriptures citing reasons/causes/effects etc?

Please cite authentic references in your answers.

Comment: This is quite interesting question. I wonder why it remained unnoticed for long. Anyway will try my luck if possible.